# Regular expression to find all occurences of a string then find the next whitespace after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

```
$("#idofreplybox").on('keyup, keydown',function(){
    var e = $(this).html();
    if (e.indexOf(@) !== -1){}else{
        var d = find all occurences of @
        var f = find the next whitespace after that @
        change the text between var d and var f to blue
    }
});
```

Using this code, when somebody types `@steve`, their name should turn blue. However I am not sure of the regular expression I need to change the text within my code block to javascript code.

Sorry if this seems obvious to you, but I am a regular expression noob so therefore I cannot work out what I need to write.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` for word boundary.

For example :

```
"test @username bla bla".replace(/@(\w+)\b/g, "<span class=user>$1</span>")
```

gives

```
"test <span class=user>username</span> bla bla"
```

Comment: so how can I use this in terms of the function?

Comment: Well, it depends how you use your code. You **can't** change the color in textarea for example, you need either to display the text in a different container or to use some [contentEditable container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).

Answer (score 1):

Using @dystroy's regex:

```
    (function($){
$("#idofreplybox").keyup(function(){
    var e = $(this).html();

    if (e.length && /@(\w+)\b/.test(e)){
        e = e.replace(/@(\w+)\b/g, '<span style="color: blue;">$1</span>');
        $(this).html(e);
    } else {

    }
});}
)(jQuery);
```

But note that you cant use html inside a textbox, use content editable elements or a proxy/dummy which will act as a textbox and copy the contents/html to a div.

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCTs8/)

The $1 refers to the first paranthesis () match, $2 to the second and so on